# Algorithm to purchase maximum items

Tags: algorithm

We are having N gold coins and M silver coins. There are k items each having some cost, A gold coins and B silver coins, where A or B can be zero also.

What can be algorithm to purchase maximum number of items?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such, and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Its not a homework. I am stuck during a problem and can't find a way to do.

Comment: Fair enough. I shouldn't have assumed.

Comment: How much silver coins is one gold coin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this problem, every item has a two dimensional cost. Let item i have cost c[i] = 
< a, b > where a is the cost in gold coins and b in the cost of silver coins.

The items can now be *partially* ordered so that item i is 'not-more-expensive' than item j if

```
c[i] = <a, b>    c[j] = <a', b'>  and    a <= a' AND b <= b'
```

Note that this is a *partial* order. Two items <1, 2> and <2, 1> are not comparable in this partial ordering; neither one is not-more-expensive than the other.

It is now clear that a greedy algorithm can safely buy items as long as they are 'not-more-expensive' compared to *every* other item remaining, but when there are multiple non-comparable items available, more analysis (e.g. search) can be needed.

For example, if the costs are

```
 <1, 1>
 <2, 1>
 <1, 2>
 <3, 3>
```

this results in this partial order:

```
        <1, 1>
       /      \
     <2, 1>   <1, 2>
         \   /
         <3, 3>
```

(most expensive item on the bottom). A greedy algorithm would purchase first <1, 1>. After that, both <2, 1> and <1, 2> are viable purchasing options. If the algorithm chooses to buy <2, 1>, the next to buy is then <1, 2> because it is now not-more-expensive than all other remaining items (<3, 3>).

Simple greedy algorithms can fail. With the setup <2, 1>, <1, 2>, <3, 0> and initial amount of coins gold = 4, silver = 2, the optimal solution is to by <1, 2> and <3, 0>, but buying <2, 1> first leads to being able to purchase only that item (purchases is left with <2, 1> coins that doesn't allow to buy any of the two remaining items).

I would approach this buy building the partial order structure and then performing a backtracking search. If time constraints wouldn't allow for full backtracking, I would use limited backtracking as a heuristics for an otherwise greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

#### Is this the Knapsack Problem?

The problem you described is not the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Here, you only want to maximize the number of items, not their total cost. In the Knapsack problem, you're interested instead in maximizing the total cost, while respecting the sack's capacity. In order words, you want to grab the most valuable items that would fit in your sack. You don't really care about how many of them, but only that they're the most valuable ones!

Below, we'll at two variants of the problem:

1. *Single Currency* -- gold and silver coins are inter-convertible
2. *Multiple Orthogonal Currencies* -- gold coins cannot be converted to silver.

#### Single Currency Variant

Assuming you're only allowed to spend N gold coins and M silver coins, here is an algorithm that should work:

```
1. Sort the items by cost, from cheapest to the most expensive.
2. totalCost = 0; i = 1
3. while totalCost <= goldToCost(N) + silverToCost(M) + item[i].cost
4.    totalCost = totalCost + items[i].cost
5.    i++
6. endWhile
7. return i
```

This algorithm only takes *O(nlogn)* time because of the sorting.

#### Multi-Currency Variant

The above solution assumes that the two currencies can be converted to each other.  Another variation of the problem involves orthogonal currencies, where the two currencies are not convertible to each other. In this case, all costs will be specified as vectors.

In order to solve this problem using a dynamic programming algorithm. We need to ask if exhibits the following two traits:

1. [Optimal Substructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure). Is the optimal solution to the problem be derived from optimal solutions to its subproblems? For instance, let `S(M, N)` be the maximum number of items we can buy using M gold coins and N silver coins.  Can we derive `S(M, N)` using a recurrence relation?
2. [overlapping Subproblems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblem). Are the subproblems of S(M, N) used over and over to compute bigger subproblems?

Imagine a two-dimensional table with N rows and M columns. The

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+---+
|   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | N |
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+---+
| 0 |   |   |   |   |     |   |
| 1 |   |   |   |   |     |   |
| 2 |   |   |   |   | ... |   |
| 3 |   |   |   |   |     |   |
| : |   |   |   |   |     |   |
| M |   |   |   |   |     |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+---+
```

Our algorithm essentially will fill out this table. In row `i`, column `j` `S[i, j]` with the maximum number of items that can be bought using i gold coins and j silver coins.

To complete the table, we could use two lexicographically sorted arrays, `I` and `D`. In the first, gold as primary sort key, and silver seconday. In the second, silver is primary, and gold secondary. Filling out the 0-th row and column is straight-forward. We then traverse the two sorted arrays in tandem, we can then use the following recurrence to complete the table

```
S[0, 0] = 0
S[i, j] = 0   if i < 0 or j < 0 
S[i, j] = max(S[i-1,j-1] + d[i-1,j-1], S[i-1,j] + d[i-1,j], S[i,j-1] + d[i,j-1])
```

where `d[i*,j*]` is number additional items you can buy using `<i,j> - <i*, j*>`, where `<i*, j*>` is one of `{<i-1, j-1>, <i-1, j>, <i, j-1>}`. In other words, how much more you can buy using the remaining money. The search to compute this involves doing a binary search on one of the two lexicographically sorted sequences (`I` or `D`).

This solution takes *O((MN + n)logn)* time to compute and uses *O(MN + n)* space.

Comment: This works for single-currency situations, which maybe this is (if e.g. one gold = 10 silver and you don't have to worry about getting change). If they have two completely orthogonal cost dimensions, e.g. gas and credits in a Starcraft-type economy :), it's not obvious to me how to generalize this.

Comment: @Dougal: That could well be another SO question, actually. In that model, all costs will be vectors. With the operators "<=", "+" redefined to operate on vectors, the above algorithm could still be made to work with minimal change, specifically to lines 2 and 3.

Comment: I don't think that necessarily works directly: you have to manage tradeoffs between the different dimensions. Imagine a case where you have lots of gas and a few credits: it's better to get high-gas, low-credit items. You also have to worry about exhausting one resource but stil being able to get items that don't require that resource. There are a lot more intricacies to worry about, and I don't think any trivial patch is going to fix it. Presumably in this case gold and silver are convertible and it doesn't matter, though the OP hasn't specified.

Comment: @Dougal: You're right, this is more involved. It might involve two lexicographic sortings. In the first, gold as primary sort key, and silver seconday. In the second, silver is primary, and gold secondary.  Since you need to use up your supplies of gold and silver, you have two cases: 1. no items requires both currencies 2. some items require both currencies. Case 1 is trivial. Case 2 would involve some kind of DP or backtracking search algorithm. You might want to post a new question for it.

Comment: @Dougal +1 for reference to StarCraft :)

Comment: @rrufai Yeah, the gold and silver are completely seperate i.e. not convertible. I also thought about the cases you mentioned above and was stuck at the second case.

Comment: @Shashwat: Dougal's approach would be one way to go. I'll try expand my answer to include orthogonal currencies.

Answer (score -2):

There is no "algorithm."

You're describing a version of the Knapsack Problem, a well-known NP-complete problem. For SMALL versions of the problem, with small N,M, and k, you just go through all the different combinations. For larger versions, there is no known way to find an "optimal" solution that takes less than the lifetime of the universe to compute.

The closest thing there is to solving this involves a field known as linear programming. It's... not a simple thing, but you can go read up on it if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For value of k around 30, will it take much time to take all possible combinations?

Comment: Don't wait up for it. A naive implementation could handle a sack holding up to about, oh, six items or so. NP-complete problems become impractical to solve *very* quickly.

Comment: If you have 30 items then there are 2^30 possible combinations of items you can purchase, which is only roughly 1 billion.  Calculating the cost of each requires you to sum up to 60 numbers (gold and silver for each of 30 items), so it would only take you about 60 billion operations, which isn't too bad.

Comment: The fact that it is NP complete certainly does not imply that there is no algorithm. What it means is that there is no known  polynomial-time algorithm, and none can exist unless P=NP (and most computer scientists believe that P≠NP). An algorithm that takes a long time to complete is still an algorithm.

Furthermore, I believe a pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming algorithm can be found for this case. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm

Comment: And, also, are you completely sure this is a knapsack problem? And also, restricted knapsack does have faster solution, I don't remember the details by heart, but maybe it would help?

Comment: Of course there's an algorithm, in fact the comments have already pointed out a couple of algorithms.